# How to create Stripe Card Token on Backend Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, nest

I am trying to implement Stripe API Payment flow in Backend Nest.js.

I am using [stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe) package and the scenario I have implemented is

1- Payment Method will be Created
2- Create Payment Intent
3- Confirm Payment Intent
4- Capture Payment Intent

I have an issue in the first step of Creating a Payment Method (I am a creating a payment method for the payment Id to be used in 2nd step) but I am getting an error.

For Creating a Payment Method, I used this

```
const paymentMethod = await this.stripe.paymentMethods.create({
       type: 'card',
       card: {
          token: token.id,
       },
});
```

For Creating token, I used this

```
const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
    number: '4242424242424242',
    exp_month: 10,
    exp_year: 2024,
    cvc: '314',
  },
});
```

but I'm facing this error

`Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing. To enable raw card data APIs in test mode, see https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-api`

Users Stripe Cards info ( Number, CVV, exp year, exp month ) is stored in database so I will be replacing the test card info with those.

After some research I found that token Id can be generated on Frontend with the help of Stripe Elements and strip.js library.

How can I resolve this issue? Should I get the token from the Frontend?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [support article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis) linked in the error.

If you're just doing this for testing, you can use the linked test cards with their payment method ids like `pm_card_visa` etc.

It is recommended to collect card details securely via ELements & Stripe.js. But, if this is how you're planning to operate for real, you need to understand the [PCI implications](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) and contact Stripe's support team: https://support.stripe.com/contact